# Cookie Monster vs Cookies Monster

Tags: grammatical-number

Is there any grammar reason why Cookie Monster is not Cookie**s** Monster, in plural. In other languages, its name is translated into plural, otherwise it could be interpreted as it was made of cookie.

Thx

Comment: In general, when a noun is used as an adjective, the singular form is used.  There are exceptions, but nothing that would seem applicable here.  "Cookie", in this case, is being used in the sense of a "mass noun", and hence would not be pluralized.  Just like a factory producing cookies is a "cookie factory", not a "cookies factory".

Comment: @HotLicks good point, great explanation.

Comment: Other examples:  "apple tree"  and "book shelf".